# How to add values based on variable name from different files in python

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two different files, first file has the variable name 'InstanceType' and other variables. The second file has the same variable name 'InstanceType' which have other variable based on classification. I want to add second variable data by adding columns based on variable 'InstanceType'.
Here is my code:

```
df=pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(uploaded['spot-prices-2021-05-16.xlsx']))
df
```

Input:

```
    AvailabilityZone    InstanceType    ProductDescription  SpotPrice   ymd_hms(Timestamp)
0   us-east-1f           r5a.4xlarge    Windows             1.0210     2021-05-16 21:14:12
1   us-east-1c           r5a.4xlarge    Windows             1.0210     2021-05-16 21:14:12
2   us-east-1b           r5a.4xlarge    Windows             1.0210     2021-05-16 21:14:12
3   us-east-1a           r5a.4xlarge    Windows             1.0210     2021-05-16 21:14:12
4   us-east-1d           p3.8xlarge  Red Hat Enterprise Linux   3.8020  2021-05-16 21:14:07
```

1st file csv

2nd file input

```
InstanceType    vCPU    GPUs    Memory (GiB)    Baseline Performance / vCPU CPU Credits Earned
0   t4g.nano    2       NaN     0.5             0.05      6.0           NaN
1   t4g.micro   2       NaN     1.0             0.10      12.0          NaN 
2   t4g.small   2       NaN     2.0             0.20      24.0          NaN 
3   t4g.medium  2       NaN     4.0             0.20      24.0          NaN 
4   t4g.large   2       NaN     8.0             0.30      36.0          NaN
```

```
df3=pd.merge(df,df2, on='InstanceType', how= str('outer'))
```

output:

```
AvailabilityZone    InstanceType    ProductDescription  SpotPrice   ymd_hms(Timestamp)  vCPU    GPUs    Memory (GiB)    Baseline Performance / vCPU CPU Credits Earned / Hr GPU Mem (Gib)   

0        us-east-1f   r5a.4xlarge   Windows             1.0210      2021-05-16 21:14:12   NaN   NaN     NaN               NaN              NaN
```

Expected outcome is- it should get all values based on 'InstanceType' and display in each row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why is there 3 output? do you mean input or output?

Comment: also, using xlsx is not good. see if you can make it an open-source format like csv. it enables more features such as using native libraries rather than locked to just using pandas.

Comment: two inputs. 1 output

Comment: your two dataframes all have different isntancetype. there is no common instancetype. how to combine like that?

Comment: i have tied with .csv as well. But the output is not coming with variable values in the same row. 2nd file values get added blow.

Comment: no, 2nd data frame has the same values as 1st data frame but not in order.

Comment: we can fix the badly-formatted csv values, dont worry. try uploading the csv. very hard to get support for closed-source formats like xlsx. you have better luck and more support from the community with csv format.

Comment: in your example, the 2nd dataframe has different values. try uploading the CSVs directly to here (as file or text). then, it will be easier for us.

Comment: Are you sure this is a full example? not a minimal one? I see `r5a.4xlarge` only exists in the first input

Comment: Also, as indicated by @Joshua, there is no common values between the two dataframes

Comment: both files have the same values of InstanceType but are not in order. I want 2nd file values to get added with the first file based on the InstanceType variable.

Comment: Do you want to merge the common values? or concatenate the different values?

Comment: i want to add values from 2nd file by verifying InstanceType in first file.

Comment: upload a bigger CSV sample. hard to see from your limited copy-pasted sample. it's okay if the CSV format is bad. we can fix it.

Comment: how to upload csv here..

Comment: upload as text using `code` quotes or you can upload to google drive and send a link here.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/113VVCbdiGA0FQoAnuBK-0ldzIojq6w9g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GZYu1BRkXzBdUH3oKKa-9VhL32Cy5gMv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: enable the google drive file for public access. now the access is restricted

Comment: enabled to be used by public

Comment: Did you change the file format from xlsx to csv?

Comment: Yes both are in .csv format.

Comment: @NIrbhayMathur I did a complete solution. Let me know if you can run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done what you wanted. You can **import the output file to pandas** and it will show **exactly what you wanted**. Generate the "combined.csv" first then run the import code.

Here is the code to import:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('combined.csv')

print(df)
```

And here is the code to generate the "combined.csv". It takes 30 seconds to run. Ensure that both source CSVs are the same folder as the code.

```
import re
import os
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io
def enforceWhitelist(temp5): # function to ensure only the characters we want are allowed
    new = re.sub('[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_:.\-]+' ,'', temp5) #regex pattern for whitelisting
    return new
def getInfo(temp9): #function to return the details from the 2nd(sub) csv as string
    global listnamesY
    for temp10 in range(len(listnamesY[0])):
        temp12 = ""
        for temp11 in range(len(listnamesY)):
            temp12 = temp12 + listnamesY[temp11][temp10]+","
        if temp9 in temp12:
            return temp12
    return temp9+","+("NOT_FOUND,"*(len(listnamesY)-1))
tempmain = [] #this is the array with all the lines of the original 1st(main) csv
with open("spot-prices-2021-05-16.csv") as main_in:
    for temp1 in main_in:
        tempmain.append(temp1)
tempsub = [] #this is the array with all the lines of the 2nd(sub) csv
with open("InstanceAWS.csv") as sub_in:
    for temp2 in sub_in:
        tempsub.append(temp2)
listnames1 = [] #this is the array with the names of columns of 1st(main) csv
listnames2 = [] #this is the array with the names of columns of 2nd(sub) csv
listnamesX = [] #this is the array with actual columns of 1st(main) csv
listnamesY = [] #this is the array with actual columns of 2nd(sub) csv
f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f): #to redirect stdout to string
    for temp3 in range(len(tempmain[0].split(";"))):

        listnames1.append(enforceWhitelist(tempmain[0].split(';')[temp3]+"_1"))
        exec(listnames1[temp3]+" = []")
        for temp4 in range(len(tempmain)):
            if temp4 > 0:
                exec(listnames1[temp3]+".append('"+enforceWhitelist(tempmain[temp4].split(';')[temp3])+"')")
        exec("listnamesX.append("+enforceWhitelist(tempmain[0].split(';')[temp3]+'_1')+")")
    for temp3 in range(len(tempsub[0].split(","))):
        listnames2.append(enforceWhitelist(tempsub[0].split(',')[temp3]+"_2"))
        exec(listnames2[temp3]+" = []")
        for temp4 in range(len(tempsub)):
            if temp4 > 0:
                exec(listnames2[temp3]+".append('"+enforceWhitelist(tempsub[temp4].split(',')[temp3])+"')")
        exec("listnamesY.append("+enforceWhitelist(tempsub[0].split(',')[temp3]+'_2')+")")
    for temp13 in range(len(listnames1)):
        if listnames1[temp13][:-2] == "InstanceType":
            for temp14 in range(len(listnames2)):
                print(listnames2[temp14][:-2], end=',')
        else:
            print(listnames1[temp13][:-2], end=',')
    print("")
    for temp6 in range(len(listnamesX[0])):
        for temp7 in range(len(listnamesX)):
            if listnames1[temp7][:-2] == "InstanceType":
                print(getInfo(listnamesX[temp7][temp6]), end='')
            else:
                print(listnamesX[temp7][temp6], end=',')
        print("")
s = f.getvalue() #the string with the stdout
s="No."+s #first column has no name so added a name
try:
    os.remove("combined.csv") #delete the old file to see the latest generation
except:
    pass
f2 = open("combined.csv", "w")
for temp15 in range(len(s.split("\n"))):
    f2.write(s.split("\n")[temp15][:-1]+"\n") #write to output csv file
f2.close()
```

Comment: works perfect, but took some time to compile. Is there any optimal solution to this?

Comment: also if possible can you comment on the code for my better understanding. I hope not asking a lot to work on.

Comment: @NIrbhayMathur You're welcome. This will around 30 seconds to compile. It takes longer because it doesn't use 3rd party libraries like pandas t(his is pure python). Sure, I will try to comment it now so that you can understand better.

Comment: @NIrbhayMathur I added some comments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your data is that the CSV files, you put in the comments, are delimited by a semicolon `;` not comma the default one `,`

Also, it's recommended to use `pandas.read_csv` even if you have an Excel sheet, you can convert it to CSV first with `to_csv` method and then read it as CSV.

I assume you already read two CSV files, so here is my solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('spot-prices-2021-05-16.csv', delimiter=';')
df2 = pd.read_csv('InstanceAWS.csv')
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='InstanceType', how='outer')

print(df_merged.head)
```

Comment: in olden days, we merged without 3rd party libraries. like how i did in my answer 

Comment: That's a lot of code, man! :D I think you could do it with `sed` as well. Probably would take much fewer lines before going to Python

Comment: @ezzeddin , you solution does not make any difference. I am getting same output.